# Keep receiving error: expected primary-expression before ' , ' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

I'm kinda new to C++ however, this was a code that was provided to me and I was told to do some edits but very few. I Keep getting the error for two lines of code:

```
MyFrame() : wxFrame((wxFrame *)NULL, -1,  wxT("wxTimerDemo " + wxDataTime::Now().Format("%c"))
                       , wxPoint(50,50), wxSize(500,300))
```

and

```
dc.DrawText(wxT("Testing"), 40, y);
```

The top one is the only code edited which was followed exactly as it should've.

Full code:

```
// Render timer - use of a timer
//  http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Making_a_render_loop
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/timer.h>

// prototypes
class BasicDrawPane;
class MyFrame;

// class definitions
class RenderTimer : public wxTimer
{
    BasicDrawPane* pane;
public:
    RenderTimer(BasicDrawPane* pane);
    void Notify();
    void start();
};

#define wxT(x)



class BasicDrawPane : public wxPanel
{

public:
    BasicDrawPane(wxFrame* parent);

    void paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt);
    void render( wxDC& dc );

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};



class MyApp: public wxApp
{
    bool OnInit();

    MyFrame* frame;
public:

};


RenderTimer::RenderTimer(BasicDrawPane* pane) : wxTimer()
{
    RenderTimer::pane = pane;
}

void RenderTimer::Notify()
{
    pane->Refresh();
}

void RenderTimer::start()
{
    wxTimer::Start(10);
}

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
    RenderTimer* timer;
    BasicDrawPane* drawPane;

public:
    MyFrame() : wxFrame((wxFrame *)NULL, -1,  wxT("wxTimerDemo " + wxDataTime::Now().Format("%c"))
                        , wxPoint(50,50), wxSize(500,300))
    {

        drawPane = new BasicDrawPane( this );

        timer = new RenderTimer(drawPane);
        Show();
        timer->start();
    }
    ~MyFrame()
    {
        delete timer;
    }
    void onClose(wxCloseEvent& evt)
    {
        timer->Stop();
        evt.Skip();
    }
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

// event table for MyFrame
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_CLOSE(MyFrame::onClose)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show();

    return true;
}

// event table for BasicDrawPane
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(BasicDrawPane, wxPanel)
EVT_PAINT(BasicDrawPane::paintEvent)
END_EVENT_TABLE()



BasicDrawPane::BasicDrawPane(wxFrame* parent) :
wxPanel(parent)
{
}


void BasicDrawPane::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}


void BasicDrawPane::render( wxDC& dc )
{
    static int y = 0;
    static int y_speed = 2;

    y += y_speed;
    if(y<0) y_speed = 2;
    if(y>200) y_speed = -2;

    dc.SetBackground( *wxWHITE_BRUSH );
    dc.Clear();
    dc.DrawText(wxT("Testing"), 40, y);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`#define wxT(x)` transforms any x to blank.
`dc.DrawText(wxT("Testing"), 40, y);`  becomes `dc.DrawText( , 40, y);` and now the error is obvious.

You should define the macro like

```
#define wxT(x) x
```

or

```
#define wxT(x) (x)
```

Defining the macro wxT is not a good use case, it should be defined when you `#include <wx/string.h>`, thus `#define wxT(x)` should be removed from your code. For more information visit [#define wxT  ( string )](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/group__group__funcmacro__string.html#ga437ea6ba615b75dac8603e96ec864160). Note that since wxWidgets 2.9.0 you shouldn't use wxT() anymore in your program sources (it was previously required if you wanted to support Unicode).

Comment: Thank you that fixed my issue!

Comment: That's clearly the reason for the error, but the solution isn't really #defining wxT yourself; it should be already defined by wx headers. So just remove the definition altogether, or better yet, don't even use wxT unless your wxWidgets is very old.